how to import React lazy when component use redux compose - has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'
There is component structure looks as below is exported with compose from redux.
TestInspector.tsx
export interface TestInspectorProps {
  closeInspector: () => void;
  onExpand: () => void;
  isFullScreen: boolean;
  selectedTest:any;
}

const TestInspector = (props: TestInspectorProps) => {
  ...

  return {<>....</>}
}

const mapStateToProps = {
  ...
}

const mapPropsToConfigs = {
  ...
}

export default compose<any>(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  connectRequest(mapPropsToConfigs)
)(TestInspector);

I am trying to lazy load TestInspector.
App.tsx
const TestInspector = lazy(
  () => import('./inspectors/TestInspector/TestInspector')
);

const App = () => {

  const testProps = {
    closeInspector: ***somefunction***,
    onExpand: ***somefunction***,
    isFullScreen: true,
    selectedTest: ***somedata***,
  };

  return (
    {/* ***getting error here *** */}
    <TestInspector {...testProps}>
    </TestInspector>
  )
}

I am getting the error:

Type '{ closeInspector: () => void; onExpand: () => void;
isFullScreen: boolean; selectedTest: any; }' has no properties in
common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.

How do I fix this?

In React with TypeScript, IntrinsicAttributes is an interface that React automatically includes as part of the props for every JSX element. It represents the built-in attributes common to all JSX elements, such as key and ref. https://www.dhiwise.com/post/the-ultimate-guide-to-react-intrinsicattributes
So your props are not correct.
// TestInspector.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { connectRequest } from 'some-library'; // adjust this import based on your project

export interface TestInspectorProps {
  closeInspector: () => void;
  onExpand: () => void;
  isFullScreen: boolean;
  selectedTest: any;
}

const TestInspector: React.FC<TestInspectorProps> = (props) => {
  const { closeInspector, onExpand, isFullScreen, selectedTest } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Your component JSX here */}
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({
  // map your state to props
});

const mapPropsToConfigs = {
  // map your props to configs
};

export default compose<any>(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  connectRequest(mapPropsToConfigs)
)(TestInspector);


// App.tsx
import React, { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';

const TestInspector = lazy(() => import('./inspectors/TestInspector/TestInspector'));

const App = () => {
  const somefunction = () => {
    // Define your function logic here
  };

  const somedata = {
    // Define your data here
  };

  const testProps = {
    closeInspector: somefunction,
    onExpand: somefunction,
    isFullScreen: true,
    selectedTest: somedata,
  };

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <TestInspector {...testProps} />
    </Suspense>
  );
};

export default App;

EDIT: you are using Typescript the TestIspectorProps are being inferred, the first point of call is specifying what the props are with the interface.
You may also want to consider using lazy with props:
const TestInspector = lazy<React.ComponentType<TestInspectorProps>>(() =>
  import('./inspectors/TestInspector/TestInspector')
);


You appear to be using the exact same props as the OP. Please explain what the difference is and how this code/answer addresses and resolves the error OP has.
